Unable to fetch Voucher Transaction Details in Tally XML
When I am trying to fetch all the Voucher details from Tally through XML, I am unable to get any transaction details like amount, quantity and discount details of that voucher (take payment voucher for example). How do I get these details?
I tried the following XML body:
<ENVELOPE Action="">
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>
        <ID>CustomVoucherCollection</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>{{currentCompany}}</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
                <SVFROMDATE TYPE="Date">1-1-2024</SVFROMDATE>
                <SVTODATE TYPE="Date">1-4-2024</SVTODATE>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CustomVoucherCollection">
                        <TYPE>Vouchers</TYPE>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>*,*.*</NATIVEMETHOD>
                    </COLLECTION>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>

Response contains the PartyName, GSTIN, LedgerName, and other details, but no transaction details.

Just add  LedgerEntries.*,InventoryEntries.* or whatever field you want inside NativeMethod tag

This works quite well. Do you have documentation on all the fields available in Tally?

Lets say,if you want voucher fields, then export voucher in xml , each xml tag is field or
Install Tally developer application and in schema tab all objects and fields are listed
